# jQuery validation not validating proper on submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am usinng [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), and have used so many times for form validating but facing this issue first time and don't understand why not validating.

**Issue:** When I click first time on submit button, form validation not appering but When I hit second time validation message appears.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('submit', 'form#register-form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#register-form").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules : {
                firstname : "required",
                lastname : "required"
            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages : {
                firstname : "Please enter your first name",
                lastname : "Please enter your last name"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<h1>Register here</h1>

<form action="#" method="post" id="register-form">
    <div class="label">
        First Name
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <br />
    <div class="label">
        Last Name
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
    <br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/68vgh7x1/1/

Any idea where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you are initializing the validation plugin only when the first submit is done, so the plugin is not getting called during the first submit operation.

You need to initialize the validation plugin out of the submit handler. Instead of using your own submit handler you can use the `submitHandler` option provided by the validation framework to submit the form - it will be called only of the form is valid. else in the submit handler you will have to check whether the form is valid.

```js
 $("#register-form").validate({

     // Specify the validation rules
     rules: {
         firstname: "required",
         lastname: "required"
     },

     // Specify the validation error messages
     messages: {
         firstname: "Please enter your first name",
         lastname: "Please enter your last name"
     },
     
     submitHandler: function(){
         //do your form submit here
         return false;
     }
 });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<h1>Register here</h1>

<!-- The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit -->
<form action="#" method="post" id="register-form">
    <div class="label">First Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
    <br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
    <br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling method onsubmit. Instead of this validate is called on DOM ready.
Have a look at this :

**http://jsfiddle.net/68vgh7x1/3/**

```
 $("#register-form").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules : {
            firstname : "required",
            lastname : "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages : {
            firstname : "Please enter your first name",
            lastname : "Please enter your last name"
        }
    });
    // adding submit event is unnecessary.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5, I suggest using the element properties:

```
required="true"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sud6L2bn/

Source: http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

PS: consider using the label element for labelling fields.